# Assigning a 2 byte variable to a 3 byte register?

Tags: c

My Watch dog timer has a default value of `0x0fffff` and i want to write a 2 byte variable (u2 compare) in it. What happens when i assign the value simply like this

```
wdt_register = compare;
```

What happens to most significant byte of register?

Register definition. It's 3 bytes register containing H, M, L 8bit registers. 4 most significat bits of H are not used and then it's actually a 20 bit register. Datasheet named all of them as WDTCR_20.

My question is what happens when i assign a value to the register using this line (just an example of 2 byte value written to 3 byte register) :

```
WDTCR_20 = 0x1234;
```

Comment: Variables aren't registers.

Comment: What sort of system has *three* byte registers? Can you clarify?

Comment: What is the declaration of `wdt_register`?

Comment: Please update your posted question with the toolchain you are using as well as the target processor and target environment in order to help other people who may see your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your WDT is a so-called special function register. In hardware, it may end up being three bytes, or it could be four bytes, some of which are fixed/read-only/unused. Your compiler's implementation of the write is itself implementation-dependent if the SFR is declared in a particular way that makes the compiler emit SFR-specific write instructions.

This effectively makes the result of the assignment implementation-dependent; the high eight bits might end up being discarded, might set some other microarchitectural flags, or might cause a trap/crash if they aren't set to a specific (likely all-zeros value). It depends on the processor's datasheet (since you didn't mention a processor/toolchain, we don't know exactly).

For example, the AVR-based atmega328p datasheet shows an example of such a register:

[image]

In this case, the one-byte register is actually only three bits, effectively (bits 7..3 are fixed to zero on read and ignored on write, and could very well have no physical flip-flop or SRAM cell associated with them).